# Where to place password files for apache?

Tags: security, apache, authentication

As I am deploying apps today, I asked myself what would be the best practise for Apache Password files storage.

For example :

- I have several vhosts based upon ServerName, each declared in individual files in `/etc/apache/sites-available`
- Some of these vhosts are password protected using the htpasswd utility.
- No accounts are common across several vhosts. That means each vhosts has it's own password file.
- Each of these websites is deployed is `/var/www/projectname`
- Since these apps are built by continous integration no password files can be put inside project folder. They would be deleted upon next deployment.

Where to put those files then?

Answer (score 0):

First of all apache basic-auth is garbage and should be avoided.  In any case if you have authentication make sure its over https,  otherwise its completely useless.  (And **YES**,  [SO's authentication is completely and totally useless because its not over https](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69171/why-doesnt-the-stack-overflow-team-fix-the-firesheep-style-cookie-theft).)

If you must use apache's auth use `AuthDigestFile` and store the file outside of the document root.  Make sure your web application doesn't have read access.

Comment: Hm. I am well aware of those things but still that is not answering my question. Outside the documentroot is a but vague.